# Finding time series mean variance skewness of stationary time series

Tags: time-series

Given a model for a stationary time series $r_t$, written as:
$r_t=\epsilon_t$ and $\epsilon_t=\sqrt{h_t} z_t$,
where $z_t$ follows $N(0,1)$ and $h_t$ is some positive random variable, which is independent of  $z_t$.

Is the mean of $r_t=0$ and  variance equals to $h_t$, skewness=$E(z_t^3)$, kurtosis=$E(z_t^4)$?

if $h_t=\omega+ \alpha \epsilon^2_{t-1}$, can anyone recall what model it is? is it a AR model?

Can anyone help? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We compute
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[r_t] &= \mathbb E[\sqrt{h_t}z_t]=\mathbb E[\sqrt{h_t}]\mathbb E[z_t] = 0,\\\\
\mathsf{Var}(r_t) &= \mathbb E[r_t^2] - \mathbb E[r_t]^2 = \mathbb E[h_t]\mathbb E[z_t^2] = \mathbb E[h_t]\\\\
\gamma_1(R_t) &= \mathbb E\left[\left(\frac{r_t-\mathbb E[r_t]}{\sqrt{\mathsf{Var}(r_t)}}\right)^3\right] = \mathbb E\left[h_t^{3/2}\right]\\\\
\mathsf{Kurt}(r_t) &= \frac{\mathbb E[(r_t-\mathbb E[r_t])^4]}{\mathbb E[(r_t-\mathbb E[r_t])^2]} = \frac{\mathbb E[r_t^4]}{\mathbb E[r_t^2]} = \frac{\mathbb E[h_t^2]\mathbb E[z_t^4]}{\mathbb E[h_t]\mathbb E[z_t^2]}=\frac{3\mathbb E[h_t^2]}{\mathbb E[h_t]}.
\end{align}
If $h_t=\omega+\alpha\varepsilon_{t-1}^2$, then $$r_t = z_t\sqrt{\omega+\alpha\varepsilon_{t-1}^2} $$ which certainly isn't an AR process.

Comment: thanks! two more further questions, do you know under what condition, $r_t$ is normal? and if it's not an AR, what process it is?

Comment: I don't know, afraid I only took an introductory time series course in undergrad :(